# disassembly - bad results generated with ghidra but not with objdump and IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, ghidra, objdump

I am using Ghidra to analyze `libpng-compat.1.5.10.so` (downloaded from Fedora mirrors).

But it didn't load the expected disassembly. Then I used Objdump and IDA to check the code and they get the same results and process it correctly. Here are pictures of these three tools about the function `png_write_rows`:

Ghidra:

[image]

we can see that from 0x6bf9, bad results are generated.

For comparison, Objdump:

[image]

and IDA:

[image]

I know IDA is the best SRE tool, and I always thought Ghidra and IDA are the top 2. Objdump is a basic, standard and old tool, but why is it that Ghidra can't even get the correct disassembly code while the other two tools do? I use auto-analyze and import the binary file for both IDA and Ghidra.
How to correct these errors?

By adjusting analysis options，if `Non-Returning Functions - Discovered` is set as `false`, it will be correct.

Comment: (Replicated, using http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/47213828/dir/fedora_17/com/libpng-compat-1.5.10-1.fc17.i686.rpm.html). Weird. That function `entry` gets marked `noreturn`, and it takes a "Clear flow and repair" command to get it to recognize it for what it is (a simple localized `ebx` loader). After that, "D" again on the original function appears to work -- but you have to do that on *every* function using `entry`.

Comment: @usr2564301 "D" works for the extra code after "call entry", but the next lines following "call entry" get wrong disassembly.

Comment: What does the `align` mean where an Intel mnemonic should be? I think I ran into this once before and never figured out what it was.